# Pronunciation of “snake” and “snack”

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

It's sometimes hard to distinguish between these two words while speaking.
What is the correct pronunciation of these two words?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELL. Did you check the pronunciation of those words in a dictionary? If you did, what confused you about their pronunciation?

Comment: thanks for respons. yeah sure, only that when the conversation is often confused for me

Comment: Are you confused about the pronunciation of _bake_ and _back_, or _make_ and _mack_ too?

Comment: with a few sentences I can understand what is the purpose. It's just that there are a few words that have similar in pronunciation

Comment: That is why I asked if you have problems with distinguishing when somebody says _bake_ instead of _back_: The difference in pronunciation there is between those words is the same difference there is between _snake_ and _snack_.

Comment: When you say you've checked the words out in the dictionary, I think we're asking, did you click on the little [speaker](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snake) [icon](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snack) that allows you to hear the pronunciation of [snake](http://www.onelook.com/pronounce/macmillan/US/snake-American-English-pronunciation.mp3) and [snack](http://www.onelook.com/pronounce/macmillan/US/snack-American-English-pronunciation.mp3)? If so, can you elaborate more on what's confusing you?

Comment: As I know, Sometimes people from different tribes have different pronunciation with recorded in the computer because they have a different accent

Comment: @MuhammadSholihin: Ah, but that's another matter altogether. As you say, there's no single "correct" way to say the word, but you'll have to explain more about your confusion for this to be answerable, I think. You might want to try [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/snake/#en), too; it's very interesting for analyzing variability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ake" in "Snake" is pronounced like "Bake" or "Cake". "ack" in "Snack" is pronounced like "Back" or "Crack".